# Can you recommend a way to present many multiple pages of data on the web sortable

Tags: java, javascript, html, report

I have a report generated from a database containing about 100,000 entries, each entry contains about 10 columns, the data is stored on Amazon S3 and is generated monthly. I'm looking for some pointers on a way you recommend a way to present this many multiple pages of data on, and I want it to be sortable and because however I sort it it wont suit all users, ideally it should be searchable as well.

Is it possible to do purely client-side or is that unfeasible, do I need go back to the server. I don't have the database available but if needs be, the website is backed by a java servlet application running on Tomcat. A self contained library for doing this would be very useful.

Comment: export it as Excel, save it on your server and for all users return it as response... and let the end user sort or filter :)

Comment: Interesting idea, might work  but that wouldnt that mean the file (and hence reponse) was absolutely massive

Comment: it does not matter, your data is massive either way you will respond with massive data...

Comment: sgpalit Well the traditional way would be to display only 1000 entries per page, only one page gets sent to user, and other pages only get sent if requested but user, having said that I do like your idea.

Comment: If you are going to make server-side paging it is quit impossible to sort or search client-side. For each request you need to handle it on server-side. No body needs 100.000 data which they can not read in 5 min, so the end user problem is something else according to me, you schould narrow the output result, otherwise this becomes a reporting issue where Excel's are mostly used.

Comment: Good point, yes nobody needs all 100,000 rows the trouble is that are all equal I have no way of knowing what the user wants. So your right client sorting would need all the data, so either provide search/page on server or provide as spreadsheet (or do both), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paraphrase the discussion above.

Providing search/paging in Javascript is not sensible because this would still require the user to download all the data in one go, and representing that amount of data in html is not going to work well.

So either have to provide a server backend and provide a mechanism for searching and paging. Or provide the data in a spreadsheet format then the user can use the capabilities of their spreadsheet tool, which is well suited to dealing with large volumes of data.

Im going to try the spreadsheet idea.